# Proxying to another web service with Flask

Tags: python, proxy, nginx, flask, httplib

I want to proxy requests made to my Flask app to another web service running locally on the machine.  I'd rather use Flask for this than our higher-level nginx instance so that we can reuse our existing authentication system built into our app.  The more we can keep this "single sign on" the better.

Is there an existing module or other code to do this?  Trying to bridge the Flask app through to something like httplib or urllib is proving to be a pain.

Comment: Also this question is relevant when doing AJAX services for old browsers like IE7 which do not support cross-domain security.

Comment: What specific problem are you having with httplib?

Comment: @jd: Given that flask is on the app side of WSGI, I am not sure I get all of the data to effectively forward.  For example, the Flask request object doesn't seem to include the raw request (or even the request headers) that I'd want to pass into httplib.  It's not that it's impossible, it's just a pain and I was hoping for an existing module which did it already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have an implementation of a proxy using httplib in a Werkzeug-based app (as in your case, I needed to use the webapp's authentication and authorization).

Although the Flask docs don't state how to access the HTTP headers, you can use `request.headers` (see [Werkzeug documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#base-wrappers)). If you don't need to modify the response, and the headers used by the proxied app are predictable, proxying is staightforward.

Note that if you don't need to modify the response, you should use the `werkzeug.wsgi.wrap_file` to wrap httplib's response stream. That allows passing of the open OS-level file descriptor to the HTTP server for optimal performance.

Comment: Thanks, I hacked something up this afternoon.  Having all sorts of problems with cookies, though, since httplib doesn't handle them particularly well.  Unfortunately I think I will need to modify the response to do some simple URL rewriting (ie, <src img="/static/foo.jpg"> to <src img="/myserver/proxy/static/foo.jpg">

Comment: In my case there was just one cookie to catch, so a regex did the job to parse it, it's a lot easier to setup that Python's cookie libs.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your implementation, or the code itself in the body of the answer?

Comment: Here is a [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50231825/399573) with actual implementation.

Answer (score 141):

I spent a good deal of time working on this same thing and eventually found a solution using the **requests** library that seems to work well. It even handles setting multiple cookies in one response, which took a bit of investigation to figure out. Here's the flask view function:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv  # pip package python-dotenv
import os
#
from flask import request, Response
import requests  # pip package requests


load_dotenv()
API_HOST = os.environ.get('API_HOST'); assert API_HOST, 'Envvar API_HOST is required'

@api.route('/', defaults={'path': ''}, methods=["GET", "POST"])  # ref. https://medium.com/@zwork101/making-a-flask-proxy-server-online-in-10-lines-of-code-44b8721bca6
@api.route('/<path>', methods=["GET", "POST"])  # NOTE: better to specify which methods to be accepted. Otherwise, only GET will be accepted. Ref: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#http-methods
def redirect_to_API_HOST(path):  #NOTE var :path will be unused as all path we need will be read from :request ie from flask import request
    res = requests.request(  # ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36601467/248616
        method          = request.method,
        url             = request.url.replace(request.host_url, f'{API_HOST}/'),
        headers         = {k:v for k,v in request.headers if k.lower() != 'host'}, # exclude 'host' header
        data            = request.get_data(),
        cookies         = request.cookies,
        allow_redirects = False,
    )

    #region exlcude some keys in :res response
    excluded_headers = ['content-encoding', 'content-length', 'transfer-encoding', 'connection']  #NOTE we here exclude all "hop-by-hop headers" defined by RFC 2616 section 13.5.1 ref. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.5.1
    headers          = [
        (k,v) for k,v in res.raw.headers.items()
        if k.lower() not in excluded_headers
    ]
    #endregion exlcude some keys in :res response

    response = Response(res.content, res.status_code, headers)
    return response
```

Update April 2021: `excluded_headers` should probably include all "hop-by-hop headers" defined by [RFC 2616 section 13.5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.5.1).

Comment: Edited just now to remove 'Host' from the request headers and remove a few items from the response headers.

Comment: `headers` seems to be unused?

Comment: @luckydonald I think it is fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That header loop is brilliant

Comment: @MLeonard tho it ignores the fact that `werkzeug.Headers` may store multiple values for each key. Then the header will be overriden twice or even more.

Comment: This bit saved my day, better, it saved my week!  Fantastic! Now I only need to understand @ddnomad comment, which headers have multiple values? And how to fix that?

Comment: @Evan do we need to add a new HOST header with proxy name since the original HOST header has been removed?

Comment: @Caxton `requests.request()` sets the HOST header for you, I believe.

Comment: @Evan nice solution. It doesn't handle 3xx redirections, however, since the redirection url might point to the proxied host

Comment: Could someone add how you call this in a MWE app?

Comment: This is great, many thanks! (This is what one needs to get ngrok to work with both front and back ends.) But, for me `request.host_url` includes `http://` and also a trailing slash so the replace line for me was: `request.url.replace(request.host_url, 'http://new-domain.com/')`

Comment: @Ire I encountered this problem and have added an edit to fix. All I did was replaced the header filter line with `headers = [(name, value) if (name.lower() != 'location') else (name, value.replace('http://new-domain.com/', request.host_url)) for (name, value) in resp.raw.headers.items() if name.lower() not in excluded_headers]`. This just fixes the URL in the Location header. (thanks @jbasko for pointing out the issue with the trailing slash)

Comment: You can also stream the response content, instead of reading it entirely on the server. For this replace `resp.content` above with `resp.iter_content(chunk_size=10*1024)` and add `content_type=r.headers['Content-Type']` argument to `Response` constructor.

Comment: I decorated this method with the following 3 attributes to ensure it handles requests with any paths (at least 3 levels deep, add more to handle deeper).  Not sure if there is a better way...

@app.route('/api/v1/<path1>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'PATCH'])
@app.route('/api/v1/<path1>/<path2>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'PATCH'])
@app.route('/api/v1/<path1>/<path2>/<path3>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'PATCH'])

Comment: @Evan why do we need to remove these headers from response?`excluded_headers = ['content-encoding', 'content-length', 'transfer-encoding', 'connection']`

Comment: Why do we only send the "HOST" header to the server behind the reverse proxy? I see an edit to this answer that reversed the logic from including everything BUT the "HOST" header to ONLY including the "HOST" header. Shouldn't the code be `!=`?

Comment: I seem to have an issue when uploading file in form data: 

```requests\models.py", line 149, in _encode_files
    raise ValueError("Data must not be a string.")
ValueError: Data must not be a string.```

Answer (score 9):

My original plan was for the public-facing URL to be something like `http://www.example.com/admin/myapp` proxying to `http://myapp.internal.example.com/`.  Down that path leads madness.

Most webapps, particularly self-hosted ones, assume that they're going to be running at the root of a HTTP server and do things like reference other files by absolute path.  To work around this, you have to rewrite URLs all over the place: Location headers and HTML, JavaScript, and CSS files.

I did [write a Flask proxy blueprint](https://gist.github.com/1229770) which did this, and while it worked well enough for the one webapp I really wanted to proxy, it was not sustainable.  It was a big mess of regular expressions.

In the end, I set up a new virtual host in nginx and used its own proxying.  Since both were at the root of the host, URL rewriting was mostly unnecessary.  (And what little was necessary, nginx's proxy module handled.)  The webapp being proxied to does its own authentication which is good enough for now.

Comment: Some illustration to "I set up a new virtual host" would be nice.

Comment: Definitely your last paragraph. Flask's strength is not as a proxy, so when possible, it's preferable to avoid using as one. The only valid reason I can think of is that some application logic like authentication or authorization is necessary and not supported by the other application.