# Using Python to copy Flask requests to another Flask app

Tags: python, flask

Let's say I have a Flask app running. When someone goes to any page, or makes any sort of request on the page, I want that request to be copied to another Flask app. Is there an already existing Flask plugin that would allow me to do so?

By copy I mean this:

My app is test.com. I have another Flask app running on a private machine on a private IP. When I get a GET request on test.com, I want the same GET request to be sent to the Flask app on the private app.

Comment: what do you mean by "copied"?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I'm sure you could install some sort of `@app.before_request` handler, but why?

Comment: I think you need a reverse proxy. All "big" webservers (Apache, Lighttpd, nginx) are able to do that.

Comment: nginx is great for reverse proxying - if you're not already using that I would do so - so I agree with @nkr

Comment: If the request needs to be "copied" completely, do reverse proxy. In general, if you want to talk to another Flask server, just send another request. But again, depends on how you design your app and what they do. By private IP, you mean internal ip that are only recongizable by the host? e.g  `10.10.0.15`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, the best kind of proxy is that provided by your web server. However sometimes you actually need your web application to do the proxying, in that case see this answer: [Proxying to another web service with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656363/proxying-to-another-web-service-with-flask/6666585#6666585)