# Redirect all requests from server to Flask app

Tags: python, http, flask, rate-limiting

Is there a way that I could redirect every http get request coming to server to flask application and if certain condition is satisfied the app would pass request on but if not the app would block access to requested url.
The request coming from client to server is not related to flask app but I want to filter all requests and give permission only to those who met certain condition.

I would lite to try this in flask, but I am open to every solution possible.

Comment: I think is an interested question. So if I understood, you want like a 'flask filter app' which is not the main Application? so 1. Client [GET request] ----> 'Flask app' ---> 'if commition met' ---> 'Server' ---> [Response with a URL] ---> Client?    Or in other words you want to buil like a proxy server using Flask?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to build. I would like to try it in flask but if someone suggest some other solution beside flask I would like to try it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally think Flask is a great option to handle a proxy server.

I currently don't have a straight solution as I never did it before but this is what I found around that seems legit (and will implement myself in the feature).

### MOST SIMPLE ONE

> - [By @ziozzang in Github](https://github.com/ziozzang/flask-as-http-proxy-server)

---

### Flask Dance package

> - [Proxies and HTTPS](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/proxies.html)

---

### Stack Overflow

> - [By @AArias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50231825/13903942)

### Other

---

> - [Using NGINX-reverse proxy with Flask and Docker](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-nginx-reverse-proxy-with-flask-and-docker-66854e940176)

> - [By @stewartadam in github](https://gist.github.com/stewartadam/f59f47614da1a9ab62d9881ae4fbe656)

> - [Making a flask proxy server, online, in 10 lines of code.](https://medium.com/@zwork101/making-a-flask-proxy-server-online-in-10-lines-of-code-44b8721bca6)

> - [How To Create A Flask Proxy](https://dev.to/jcowie/how-to-create-a-flask-proxy-2bpd)

> - [flask-behind-proxy 0.1.1](https://pypi.org/project/flask-behind-proxy/)