# How can I use ngrok for backend and frontend *at the same time*?

Tags: reactjs, testing, mobile, server, ngrok

I have a react app that I would like to test in mobile, but the mobile dev tools in either Chrome or Firefox are not enough.

Backend runs on `localhost:5000` and frontend on `localhost:3000`.

If I run both `ngrok http 3000` and `ngrok http 5000` and I use the link given by `ngrok http 3000` I can access my frontend but (understandly so) it can talk to my backend as it is looking for a `localhost: 5000` server relative to my phone rather than looking to the link given by `ngrok http 5000`.

My question is:

1. What is the best way of configuring my app and ngrok so that I can *simultaneously* test my app on my computer and on my phone?
2. Is there a better way of doing this without using `ngrok` at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, you can configure proxying to backend from your development server. This will enable your frontend to access backend through relative URLs (like `/api` instead of `localhost:5000/api`) from any location. In order to do this, you should add `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` to your `package.json` and then make sure your backend requests don't match something you have in your frontend, preferably by using a prefix. More details [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/).

Given you test the app only from within your local network, you don't need ngrok as you can access your development machine from the phone via its local IP. To find it out, run `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` and type the returned local IP (usually something like 192.168.X.X) in your phone instead of domain provided by ngrok.

Comment: This is perfect. Simple too. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Form your frontend where you have made configuration from API server replace this with Ngrok URL where your backend is running and then Ngrok your frontend and then you can access your frontend from anywhere