# Do I have to expose front and back ends with ngrok for MERN stack for CRUD ops to work?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, ngrok

I am developing a MERN app on my local machine.

The front end is on localhost:3000

The back end is on localhost:3003

I have in my front end code a request, like so:

`axios.get('localhost:3000/comments', params)`

Now, I use ngrok to expose the app, like so:

`ngrok start front_end back_end`

and my .yml config file looks like:

```
tunnels:
    front_end:
        proto: http
        addr: 3000
        subdomain: fakedomaintest
    back_end:
        proto: http
        addr: 3003
        subdomain: fakedomaintestback
```

My question was, do I have to expose the back end in a different way, or am I splitting the stack wrong?

**When I expose localhost:3000 and localhost:3003, I edit the CRUD lines in the front end code to match the ngrok URL, like so:**

`axios.get('fakedomaintestback.ngrok.io/comments', params)`

**and upon accessing** `fakedomaintest.ngrok.io` **it works....**

But is there an easier way wherein I do not have to edit the CRUD lines on the front end everytime I want to use ngrok for a remote prototype?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is running at `localhost:3003` then your axios call should be `axios.get('localhost:3003/comments', params)`

To address the url switching:

You could use `dotenv` to set up environment variables for your application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

How it would work is you would create a `.env` file in the root folder of your react application containing the following:

```
BACKEND_HOST=localhost:3003
```

Then in your code you could change all your network calls to the following:

```
axios.get(`${process.env.BACKEND_HOST}/comments`, params)
```

When you want to switch to using ngrok, you can simply change the value in the `.env` file.

If you happen to be using Create React App, `.env` files will already be supported, but you'll have to prefix all your variables with `REACT_APP`, so `BACKEND_HOST` would become `REACT_APP_BACKEND_HOST`

Comment: This totally answers the question of having to change the value in the front.

But just to be clear, exposing the back is always necessary if I'm tunneling into my app?

Comment: You would only need to use ngrok if you want to expose your app to the external internet. If you're only using it on your local computer, just using `localhost:3003` is fine

Comment: It does if configured correctly. If you use `create-react-app` it comes with it included