# send retrieved request as data to another flask server

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask server which get requests, and I want to send that raw request to a different flask server that is in charge of logging all of the requests made into my network.

I am trying to pass the original request (as is) to the logger flask application, but I am running into some trouble.

I tried sending request.**dict**, but it does not contain all the original data.

I also tried using pickle on the `request` object, but I get an error while trying to dump it. my code:

```
import pickle
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
        data = {'pickled': pickle.dumps(request)}
```

Error:

> _pickle.PicklingError: args[0] from **newobj** args has the wrong class

Does anyone has any suggestions on how can I do such thing?

Comment: Do you get that error during the dump or when trying to unpickle the result on the other end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proxying to another web service with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656363/proxying-to-another-web-service-with-flask) Using the requests library, it re-sends the request to another service. Your service can they do with that what you want.  It's not exactly the raw request but it may be close enough?

Comment: @JeffUK, it is close to what I want to do, but I also need all the information of the client who made the original request, which I don't when acting as a proxy.